# UnauthorizedAccessException while initializing ProximityDevice (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I want to use `ProximityDevice` in my application. If I declare it as field or in the constructor, like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
    // Constructor
    public ProximityDevice device;
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault(); 
    }
}
```

**or this:**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
    // Constructor

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
       public ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault(); 
    }
}
```

**I get**

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in SecurityClient.DLL
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll
```

**If I declare it as static code causes no problems:**

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
        // Constructor
        public static  ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();       
        }
    }
```

How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added the ID_CAP_PROXIMITY capability to your application manifest.

Comment: I forgot about those capabilities section. It worked. Do you know how to write a tag? Because I was looking for that for a long time, topic link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237805/how-to-write-data-to-nfc-tag-using-nokia-lumia-820windows-phone